# KeyError: 'bert.embeddings.LayerNorm.weight'

Tags: python, bert-language-model, embedding

Im running this code in Jetson Nano developer kit. Im getting following error.
Error log:
File "intentc.py", line 89, in 
model = BertClassifier(h_size_bert=768, h_size_classifier=50, number_labels=28,config= config)
File "intentc.py", line 43, in **init**
self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=config,ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
File "/home/hri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 1889, in from_pretrained
_fast_init=_fast_init,
File "/home/hri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2002, in _load_pretrained_model
and state_dict[checkpoint_key].shape != model_state_dict[model_key].shape
KeyError: 'bert.embeddings.LayerNorm.weight'

Script:

```
import torch
import pickle
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
# from model import tokenization_with_bert, BertClassifier
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig
from transformers.modeling_utils import PreTrainedModel

def tokenization_with_bert(tokenizer: BertTokenizer, data: list, max_len: int):
    input_ids, attention_masks = list(), list()
    for sent in data:
        encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode_plus(text=sent, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=max_len,
                                             pad_to_max_length=True, return_attention_mask=True)
        input_ids.append(encoded_sent.get('input_ids'))
        attention_masks.append(encoded_sent.get('attention_mask'))
    input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids)
    attention_masks = torch.tensor(attention_masks)
    return input_ids, attention_masks
class BertClassifier(PreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, h_size_bert, h_size_classifier, number_labels, config, freeze_bert=False, model_path=None):
        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__(config)
        self.h_size_bert = h_size_bert
        self.h_size_classifier = h_size_classifier
        self.number_labels = number_labels
        # self.criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        if model_path != None:
            #pickle load or bin file load
            self.bert = pickle.load(open("assets/saved_models/transformer/bert.pkl", "rb"))
        else:
            self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=config,ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
                                        nn.Linear(self.h_size_bert, self.h_size_classifier),
                                        nn.ReLU(), 
                                        nn.Linear(self.h_size_classifier, self.number_labels)
                                        )
        
        if freeze_bert:
            for param in self.bert.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, input_ids: torch.tensor, attention_mask: torch.tensor):
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        last_h_state_cls = outputs[0][:, 0, :]
        logits = self.classifier(last_h_state_cls)
        # logits = torch.sigmoid(logits)
        return logits

mlb=MultiLabelBinarizer()
actions=["admiration", "amusement","anger","annoyance","approval","caring","confusion","curiosity","desire","disappointment","disapproval","disgust","embarrassment","excitement","fear","gratitude","grief","joy","love","nervousness","optimism","pride","realization","relief","remorse","sadness","surprise","neutral"]
labels=mlb.fit_transform([actions])
text="list airlines flying from seattle to salt lake city"
path="/home/hri/HRI/intentc/Layer2_80/"


config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(path)


model = BertClassifier(h_size_bert=768, h_size_classifier=50, number_labels=28, config=config)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path + 'pytorch_model.bin'), strict=False)

#Bert tokenizer
bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True,config=config,ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)

TEST_INPUTS, TEST_MASK = tokenization_with_bert(bert_tokenizer, [text], 64)
model.eval()
logits = model(TEST_INPUTS, TEST_MASK)
pred_labels= torch.sigmoid(logits)
pred_labels = pred_labels.detach().cpu().numpy()
# preds = [(pred > 0.5) for pred in pred_labels ]
# preds = np.asarray(preds)
preds = (np.array(pred_labels) > 0.5).astype(int)
new_preds = preds.reshape(1,-1).astype(int)
pred_tags = mlb.inverse_transform(new_preds)
# predict_labels = actions[np.argmax(new_preds.detach().numpy())]
print(pred_tags)
```

I have tried adding ignore_mismatched_sizes=True , but still its showing the same error.